# Maven tomcat plugin - cannot invoke Tomcat manager

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, deployment, maven-tomcat-plugin

I'm trying to deploy my web app on Tomcat 7 with Maven (version 3.3.3), but I'm getting the exception listed in the title.

I've tried many solutions but no one works for me.

I had:

1. Edited `tomcat-users.xml` ($CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat-user.xml):

   ```
   <tomcat-users>
       <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
       <role rolename="manager-script"/>
       <user username="user" password="pass" roles="manager-script"/>
       <user username="user2" password="pass2" roles="manager-gui"/>
   </tomcat-users>
   ```
2. Edited `settings.xml` ($USER_HOME/.m2/settings.xml):

   ```
   <servers>
       <server>
            <id>RemoteServer</id>
            <username>user</username>
            <password>pass</password>
       </server>
   </servers>
   ```
3. Configured `pom.xml` ($MY_PROJECT/pom.xml):

   ```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version> 
        <configuration>
            <server>RemoteServer</server>
            <url>http://my.public.ip.address:8080/manager/text</url>
            <username>user</username>
            <password>pass</password>
        </configuration>   
    </plugin>
   ```
4. Edited `context.xml` ($CATALINA_HOME/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml)

   ```
    <Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
    <!--
         <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
          allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
    -->
    <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>
    </Context>
   ```

Additional notes:

- I tried to deploy both to 8.0.45 and 8.5.16 (for the latter server, the configuration in context.xml was fundamental)
- I can access the manager GUI with no problem
- The username/password in the pom "should" be an overkill, but I read around that could help, in any case I tried also without those attributes
- If I test the manager/text (for example manager/text/deploy from the browser) I get a response (FAIL - Invalid parameters supplied for command [/deploy] and that's fine)

The error I get is:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project ShareRideServer: **Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]**
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project ShareRideServer: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: **Cannot invoke Tomcat manager**
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:68)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
**Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect**
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:742)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:705)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:82)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:132)
    ... 23 more

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html According to this, username and password goes inside the server block

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in the third bullet point, I also tried without username and password in the pom.xml but only in the server block :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is: the configuration is correct. However, **always** check your firewall at work... I tried with another connection and I had no problem. It seems the firewall was silently killing all the requests.

Comment: How do you fix this on CentOS ?

Comment: The configuration is ok also for CentOS. As mentioned, you have to check your network stack in front of your machine (e.g: firewall, etc)